# Javascript Negate Shorthand

Tags: javascript

In many programming languages, we have the following ways of expressing iteration:

```
c=c+1;
```

Can be expressed as:

```
c++;
```

Likewise,

```
c=c-1;
```

Can be shortened to:

```
c--;
```

Do I have a comparable alternative to:

```
c=!c;
```

Comment: You think this `!c` is not short enough?

Comment: @AakashVerma No need to overreact. It's a question worth asking. People toggle booleans all the time.

Comment: Have you ever seen this in any other language? I think this question is not JavaScript specific

Comment: as in `let c = true; c = ! c ` or what way ?

Comment: Exactly. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @JuanMendes I figured it wouldn't be Javascript specific, but I hesitate to add tags until I know what languages the accepted answer can be implemented in. Given that it's bitwise, likely all languages.

Comment: @Dummy, that's what I am talking about. Byxor I was just trying to fill the minimum characters needed for a comment; no need to be oversmart.

Comment: Considering `c^=1` is just as short as `c!=c`, any variable name longer than one character actually is shorter using the accepted solution. `!c` is, in fact, not short enough when your variable name is `parameters.conditions[e.target.name]`

Comment: The smallest I could realistically shorten the variable to is `window.c[e.target.name]`.

Comment: @Even Hendler That's why I didn't waste my time answering ur question, where even the accepted answer , though helpful,  is not absolutely right according to the question you so proudly phrased.

Comment: @AakashVerma I apologize for getting so argumentative with you, but it's people like you who intimidate others into not asking legitimate questions. You should consider using more tact in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do it with [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or).

```
a = true // true
a ^= true // 0
a ^= true // 1
a ^= true // 0
a ^= true // 1
```

Or go full integers, code will be shorter and output more consistent

```
a = 1 // 1
a ^= 1 // 0
a ^= 1 // 1
a ^= 1 // 0
a ^= 1 // 1
```

Comment: or this ? `let c = true; c = ! c`

Comment: @VictoryOsikwemhe: no, not this :)

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's worth noting that this will take less characters than `x = !x` if you have a longer variable name. Good solution, but probably a little unusual to read at first.

Comment: Hard to call this a shorthand, maybe a longhand, but yes, its cool

Comment: @SergioTulentsev +1

Comment: The name of the variable I'm negating is long enough that this is much shorter, excellent answer.